# When trying to say “She was not [adjective]”, when do I use “Elle n’a pas été” instead of “Elle n’était”?

Tags: participe-passé, passé-composé, imparfait, passif

To provide some context, I am very new to French and I am still trying to learn simple phrases.

Of course, there are always multiple ways to express the same thing — but, I am not sure if there is a rule that I should know about.

When using Google Translate as a guide, it translates **“She was not happy”** as **“Elle n'était pas contente”** … but it translates **“She was not entertained”** as **“Elle n'a pas été divertie.”**

Any help is appreciated — Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason is that "*contente*" is an adjective and "*divertie*" is a past participle, which is essentially a verb acting as an adjective. They don't behave exactly in the same way.

It's also possible to have participle that becomes an actual adjective, in that case it's called a "participle adjective".

Answer (score 0):

*Elle n'a pas été divertie* is a passive voice, but *Elle n'était pas contente* is an active voice. For _*Elle n'a pas été divertie*, one could use the active voice *elle ne se divertissait pas*, which brings back the expression closer to the one, both using the *imparfait* tense.